# What is the command to open the shutdown dialog?

Tags: command-line, 11.10, shutdown, dialog

I would like to use a gesture to shutdown/restart my computer and I need to know the command that launches the shutdown dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper` can be used to open the following dialogs:

- Log Out (`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --logout`)

  [image]
- Restart (`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --restart`)

  [image]
- Shutdown (`/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown`)

  [image]

Answer (score 8):

To prompt only the shutdown/restart dialog, run the following command:

```
gnome-session-quit --reboot
```

Details on binding this on Ctrl-Alt-Del [here](http://simionbaws.ro/linux/ubuntu-14-04-ctrlaltdel-shutdown-dialog/).

Comment: Works perfectly in 18.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Gnome Shell if I try `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown` I obtain the dialog in the screenshot you provided, but when I click on `Shut Down` I receive another dialog (similar to the first). Only after a second confirm my system shuts down.

This method reaches the second dialog directly via command line?

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```