# How can I assign Ctrl+Alt+Delete to shutdown dialog?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shutdown

In Oneiric <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key shortcut is for the logout dialog. How can I assign it to the shutdown dialog ?

Comment: see also: http://askubuntu.com/q/53263

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding a new custom keyboard shortcut.

Disable the current <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> shortcut

Select the keyboard app from the dash

[image: screenshot of searching in dash (Unity desktop) with results]

On the shortcut tab change the current shortcut of logout to something else, say <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

[image: keyboard settings dialog]

Then click on **custom shortcut** and add a new shortcut.

[image: custom shortcut entry]

Enter *Shutdown* in the **Name** field and `/usr/lib/indicator-session/gtk-logout-helper --shutdown` in the **Command** field.

Click <kbd>apply</kbd> and assign the shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>)

[image: new shortcut shown under shortcuts in keyboard settings]

Comment: the last step does not work... :( what is "assign" the shortcut ? :(

Comment: @marc: Just click on the shortcut(initially it will display as 'Disabled' just click on it). Then the text will change to 'New Shortcut ..' at that point type your new key combination as the shortcut. eg( CTRL + ALT + DELETE)

Comment: i declared it as "Custom Shortcuts" . it lists it as "Disabled". if i click on it and press "Apply" nothing happens... :(

Comment: @marc: click on word 'Disabled' . The text will change to 'New Shrotcut' when you click on it. Then type the new shortcut on your keyboard(ie: CTRL + ALT +DELETE) and press apply.

Answer (score 0):

The "Command" field listed in @aneeshep's answer won't work for many installations. Test run the command in a terminal before assigning it to a keyboard shortcut to make sure it works as you expect. If it doesn't, try one of these alternatives:

#### Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```

#### Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off
```