# How to assign CTRL+ALT+DEL to the Gnome Shell shutdown dialog?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

My question looks an awful lot like this one: [How can I assign Ctrl+Alt+Delete to shutdown dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75343/how-can-i-assign-ctrlaltdelete-to-shutdown-dialog)
The difference is that I am using gnome shell instead of unity and I would like the gnome shell version of this window.

Comment: The solution is the same.  The only think slighlty different is how to call the settings. Go to the overview, write keyboard, choose the 'keyboard'.

Comment: I don't agree. If you create a shortcut to gtk-logout-helper as suggested in that question, you get two dialogs in a row - first the gtk dialog, and than when you click "shutdown" you get a second gnome-shell dialog. How can you run the latter directly?